# Datagrid binding with binary values

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid

I am working on a WPF datagrid custom control, where i have a Day column for each day a week and 24 columns for each hour a day, i save these values in database in seven different columns(each day a week) and datatype for those columns is Binary(3) (3 bytes * 8 bits=24), 1 bit for each hour, my intention is to bind the grid some way so each cell of  grid change its color to red/green based on bit value for that hour(red for 0 and green for 1), but i don't know where to start.

Looping is not preffered, but if there is no way out, then i should go with that as well.

Kindly help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this and let me know if this works for you:

DailyValues can be your array of integers (each integer containing the bit values for each day).

```
<UserControl.Resource>
   <HourToBrushConverter x:Key="hourToBrushConverter" />
</UserControl.Resource>


<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding DailyValues}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" >
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="1AM" Width="SizeToCells" IsReadOnly="True">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Rectangle Fill="{Binding . 
                               Converter={StaticResource hourToBrushConverter}, 
                               ConverterParameter=1}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="2AM" Width="SizeToCells" IsReadOnly="True">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Rectangle Fill="{Binding . 
                               Converter={StaticResource hourToBrushConverter}, 
                               ConverterParameter=2}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <!-- add a column for each hour (up to 24) -->
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>



[ValueConversion(typeof(int), typeof(Brush))]
public class HourToBrushConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        int dayValue = (int)value;
        int hourNumber = (int)parameter;
        int mask = GetMask(hourNumber);

        return (dayValue & mask) > 0 ? Brushes.Green : Brushes.Red;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }

    private static int GetMask(int index)
    {
       return 1 << index;
    }
}
```

I don't have access to a Visual Studio right now so I apologize for any syntax mistake.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Claudiu, but the issue is with which property i should bind the converter i don't have cell access here and column does not have background property with them.

Comment: Hi MSingh I've changed my answer to provide a solution for your binding problem. I hope this time will help.